# When we should use defmodule in .exs file

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I tried creating a mix project it did not have the `config.exs` so I created the file.

I referred `config.exs` from a phoenix project.

I see the `config.exs` does not have module definition. I tried declaring a standalone function in a `.ex` file it raised an error as expected

```
** (ArgumentError) cannot invoke def/2 outside module
```

Then I presumed that `.exs` can be written without `defmodule` then I saw the `mix.exs` it has module definition. Why it is so?

My question why it is preffred to keep `config.exs` without module definition but `mix.exs` with the definition?

When we should use defmodule in `.exs` and when not?

Comment: `.exs` is just a script and has nothing to do with whether or not you use `defmodule` inside it. My guess (I don't have any evidence to support it) is the main difference is API simplicity. With a config file, you're just saying "declare all this config". With a mix project file, you're modeling a mix project, which has certain things that need to be known about it.

Comment: @BrettBeatty That makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at `mix.exs` file you can notice the:

```
use Mix.Project
```

Now this [file](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.9.2/lib/mix/lib/mix/project.ex#L1) contains:

```
  @doc false
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      @after_compile Mix.Project
    end
  end

  # Invoked after each Mix.Project is compiled.
  @doc false
  def __after_compile__(env, _binary) do
    push(env.module, env.file)
  end
```

`@after_compile` is a macro defined in [elixir/kernel.ex](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.9.3/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2878) even if it is in a strange form and it is invoked by `__using__` from `mix.exs`. Since you cannot invoke macros outside of modules you need to have a module in your `mix.exs` file.

To illustrate this more clearly, let's try to delete the module in `mix.exs` and run the project:

```
* (ArgumentError) cannot invoke @/1 outside module
    (elixir) lib/kernel.ex:5230: Kernel.assert_module_scope/3
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.@/1
    mix.exs:2: (file)
    (mix) expanding macro: Mix.Project.__using__/1
    mix.exs:2: (file)
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/1
    mix.exs:2: (file)
```

So the answer to your question is that the hook `@after_compile` cannot be called without a module since hooks by themselves are macros. The hook most probably is used to load the project automatically after all the files were compiled.

PS: `push/3` function calls an interesting module function:

> Mix.ProjectStack.push(atom, config, file)

If you look at the source of [ProjectStack](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/35505839aa8c9555e6e2f6845997d3fc0e1a5671/lib/mix/lib/mix/project_stack.ex) module you can observe that it is a state machine based on [Agent](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/agent.ex). So basically all mix projects are pushed into the stack and they can be checked whether there are duplicates in names.

Comment: Yes I agree but use `Mix.Config` will inject the code in `__using__` not of outer scope. I was asking why `use Mix.Config` is in a module?

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks!!